# Could I get some help understanding Core Web Vitals CLS, please?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, core-web-vitals

I am having a bit of a problem with the Core Web Vitals CLS metric, on this website: https://www.digitalcitizen.ro (WORDPRESS), especially when testing on for mobile devices.

Wordpress and all of my plugins are updated to their latest version.

So let us take this link as an example: https://www.digitalcitizen.ro/5-metode-de-afla-adresa-ip-locala-routerului-tau-wireless/.

The page speed insight report for this link says that my score is 69 and that I have a CLS of 0.11 (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalcitizen.ro%2F5-metode-de-afla-adresa-ip-locala-routerului-tau-wireless%2F&tab=mobile )

I have checked many articles on this topic and the consensus seems to be that I need to set explicit sizes for my images, which I do, have no sticky headers, which I do not, not use animations, which I also don't. We also have set explicit sizes for the ad-blocks found inside all articles.

The articles I used for documenting myself on what to do are https://web.dev/cls/ and https://www.paulhoda.co.uk/how-to-fix-cls-issue-more-than-0-25-mobile/

Right now I am having doubts about the https://amp-wp.org/ plugin which we are currently using on WordPress. Could this be the culprit? The plugin wraps all and any `<img>` in a `<amp-img>` tag, like this`<amp-img><img></amp-img>` and ads AMP specific attributes to these tags.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could improve the CLS on my current setup?

Thank you!